# How to make it clear that a value is being changed using keynote

Tags: keynote

I am using keynote to make a presentation.

Let's say that following 3 lines. And the third line is something like

- We are opening a section for kids
- In June use 20% discout on all kids items
- On all kids items 30 days money back guarantee

Next I want this to happen.

- When I hit next then a big "X" come over slowly on "20%"
- When I hit next then I want "20%" to be replaced by "40%"

How do I do that in keynote. I just purchased keynote so I am using the latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the *Inspector* tool to add build-in and build-out transition to your texts and cross.

You'll have 4 build order steps :

1. cross fade in
2. cross disappear
3. text "20%" disappear
4. text "40%" appear

Play with duration and 'start build' settings to obtain desired effect.
See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1X-5AizWIJE for a screencast ;)

Comment: That's super slick. Dude I owe you a beer. Lemme know if you are ever in Miami area. :-)